# How can I fix 404 error in nginx? please,,,

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404

Following is the default value of my Nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 4x.2xx.8x.9x;
        root /home/ubuntu/jilgyungyi_gpt;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 4x.2xx.8x.9x;
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

<app.js>

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const connection = require("./configs/db-connection.js").connection;

const path = require("path");
const exp = require("constants");

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, "./public");
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.set("view engine", "hbs");

//define routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/pages"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/"));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server started on Port 3000");
});
```

I changed it for i got 404 error before.

However, I still have the same issue and I cannot solve the problem.

Curious if I need to fix nodejs to fix 404 errors?

Or I wonder if I need to modify the default file of nginx to fix it.

And I'd like you to tell me how to fix it.

Please help me

Comment: nginx never gets to `proxy_pass` part in your config, it throws 404 when it doesn't find given files in `try_files`.

Comment: Why do you have `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same location block? They cannot live together.